# Installing numpy using port (Python default version issue)

Tags: python, numpy, port, macports

I'm using Mountain Lion now and I've installed python27 and numpy using macports. The problem is that I cannot import numpy from the python. As far as I know, the default python of Mountain Lion is python 2.7.

I've tried "import numpy" with both of two python (default - 2.7.2 and port - 2.7.3).
It worked with default one but not with python 2.7.3.

I've already selected 2.7.3 using "port select".

These are the result of some port commands:

```
$ port installed|grep python
python24 @2.4.6_10 (active)
python27 @2.7.3_0
python27 @2.7.3_1 (active)
python_select @0.3_1 (active)

$ port installed|grep numpy
py24-numpy @1.6.2_0 (active)
py27-numpy @1.6.2_0 (active)
```

I really need to use numpy with python 2.7.3 which is installed using macports.

Does anyone know about this?

Comment: what does `import numpy;print numpy.__file__` do?

Comment: To me it seems like these are two python versions and both have different locations for modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you missed a step. Did you do port select like this?

```
sudo port select --set python python27
```

If py27-numpy is installed, then you must be able to import it from the MacPorts version of python 2.7. To make sure which version of python you're running, do a `which python` in the command line. If the command `python2.7 -c 'import numpy'` does not give an error, then numpy is installed for the 2.7 version in MacPorts.

Comment: I did that command before install numpy. If I type port selec --list python
Available versions for python:
 none
 python24
 python27 (active)

Comment: @user1809187, so what is the output of `python2.7 -c 'import numpy'` and `which python`?